# "Unlock Login Keyring" Instead of Login Screen

Tags: login, password

I have dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and everything but one thing works as expected: I set a password for my Ubuntu profile and did not allow automatic login. After turning on my computer/restarting from Windows to Ubuntu, I expect to be asked to type in my password before I am allowed to enter my OS, but in reality my desktop is showed and I am unable to do anything before entering my password in the "Unlock Login Keyring" pop-up window. After that, I have access to my profile, but this is not expected behavior because even without the password one can still see my Desktop and/or any application that opens automatically when the system starts (in my case it is Thunderbird, so even without entering password it is possible to read the topics of the e-mails I received).

My question is: is it possible to make my logging process go through this login screen (that can be entered if I, for example, choose to suspend my system) and not show any potentially sensitive information without entering a password?

I was not able to find any similar question here or any other forum, but if I omitted anything, I am more than happy to be corrected. Most of the similar sounding topics is about this Keyring showing up while using other applications (which is not the problem in my case) and most popular answer is to disable the password authentication (which is not something that I want to do).

Thank you, in advance, for your help and merry christmas.

Edit: **Problem solved**, autologin -- despite my confidence -- was enabled and changing that made everything work as expected.

Comment: While you wrote that you disabled automatic login, your description sure seems like automatic login is enabled. Double-check that.

Comment: You were right. This was the case. I am not sure how did this happen (initially this option was 100% disabled as I recall entering this password), so it must have been a side effect of some other configuration or just a missclick, but the important thing is that it now works as I want it to. Thank you.